# Limit with integers and continuous variable

Tags: limits

I want to prove that 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\ln^m(n)} = \infty$$
for $m > 1$.
The problem is that I can't get rid of the $\ln(n)^m$
I thought that I could calculate the limit 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{\ln^m(x)}$$ and then say that it will also be OK for $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\ln^m(n)}$. I think that I can use it in this case, but I would like a better proof because it is not in general the case that you can calculate the limit of $f(n)$ by calculating the limit of $f(x)$  (check for example $f(x) = x \sin(2 \pi x)$ )

Can someone help me?

Comment: If the continuous limit exists finitely, the same will true for the discrete case.

Comment: So you mean that you can calculate first the continuous case and if this has a limit that this is also the limit of the discrete case? So in fact you can consider the discrete case a  kind of subrow of the continuous case

Comment: Well, not "subrow", which I'm not even sure what it means, but because of the sequential definition of limit of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* compute
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{(\ln x)^m}
$$
and, if this is $\infty$, then also the limit of the sequence is $\infty$.

The converse is not true: from a sequence having a limit you can't argue that a function having those values on the integers has a limit. To be more specific, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=l$ (where $l$ can be infinity), and, for every integer $n$, you have $f(n)=a_n$, where $f$ is a function over $[0,\infty)$, you cannot conclude $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=l$.

Your example for this is good, but the converse deduction is correct: if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=l$, then also $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=l$.

Answer (score 0):

The function under the consideration is $\ f: \mathbb R_{>0}\rightarrow\mathbb R\ $ given by formula:

$$ f(x)\ :=\ \frac x{\ln^m(x)} $$

Consider function
$\ g:log\circ f\circ \exp:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R.\ $ Show that
$\ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x)=\infty.\ $ The same will hold for $\ f.$